# Jquery - Select the div within the same container class div as this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors

I'm cycling through data in a foreach loop. On each loop a container class contains the following:

```
foreach($resultarray AS $value){
        $filename = substr($value['img_file_name'],9);
        $cat_id = $value['cat_id'];
        echo '<article class="post">';
        echo '<div class="post_title">' . $value['post_title'] . '</div>';
        echo '<div class="post_info">' . 
        'Category: ' . $cat_name = get_cat_name($cat_id) .'<br />'. 
        'Year: ' . $value['post_year'] .'<br />'. 
        $value['post_desc'] .'<br />'. 
        '</div>';
        echo '<div class="link-to-post"><a href="#">Click to view</a></div>';
        echo '<a href="#" class="linktopost"><img class="post-thumb" src="img/thumb_/'.$filename.'" alt="MJbox Michael Jackson memorabilia thumbnail" /></a>';
        echo '<a href="#" class="linktopost"><img class="cover-img" src="img/post-bg-1.png" alt="test" /></a>';
        echo '<form name="form"><input type="text" class="postid" value="'.$value['post_id'].'" /></form>';
        echo '</article>';

    }
```

I have the following div made visible with Jquery when the "lintopost" link/image is clicked.

```
<div id="main-post">
        <div id="gotpostid">some text</div>
</div>
```

Currently I am using the collowing Jquery to handle when the #main-post div appears and when to get the data for that post to put inside the div.

```
$(".cover-img").click(function(){
        $("#main-post").fadeIn(1000);
        $.post("inc/fullpost.php", {postid: $('.postid').val()},
            function(output){
                $("#gotpostid").html(output).show();
            }).fail(function(x,y,z){ 
                $("#gotpostid").html(x + "<br />" + y + "<br />" + z)
            });

});
```

The problem I'm having at the moment is that the value of the input "postid" is not being selected properly. How can I select it so that it gets the value form **this** input field and not just from the first .postid it comes across which makes the id the same for every iteration.

I hope I explained myself well enough.

Answer (score 1):

1) I suggest you to use `.on('click', function() {`when you're going to add new elements on markup.

2) After clicking on image use `.find()` and `.parent()` to get exactly the input.

Comment: Hi, I tried `{postid: $(this).parent().find('input[class="postid"]').val()}`. Which seem right using parent to step back in the structure once to find an input with that name, but it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: try input.postid, not [class="postid"], so: .find('input.postid').val()